# In ssis Loading excel file when sheetname is always different

Tags: ssis

I need to load data into sql server table(2008R2) from excel file(.xlsx).My excel file name is always different and sheet name is always different too.But the number of columns and name of columns are always same.I have one sheet per excel workbook.(.xlsx file)I tried solution provided by Nitesh rai as well as Nik-shahriar Nikkhah and  others. All the solution works at first when I create the package .But when new file comes with new excel name  with new sheet name,my package fails.I am frustrated and really upset and looking for the solution for long time.No luck .Can any body help me please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I'm late to the game, but you can use a script component to loop through the excel files in the specified folder that contain part of the filename you are expecting.  This will get you the file (provided you don't have multiple excel files with similar names dropped in the same folder but for different purposes).

In order to get the sheetnames, you can can create a variable of type OBJECT and then use the following code:

```
Public Sub Main()

    GetExcelSheets()
    'SetExcelConnString(GetExcelConnString)

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub

Private Sub GetExcelSheets()
    Dim excelFile, connstr, curTable As String
    Dim excelConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim tablesInFile As DataTable
    Dim tablenameInFile As DataRow
    Dim tableCount As Integer = 0
    Dim tableIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim excelTables As String()
    Dim blnFound As Boolean = False

    ReDim excelTables(0)
    excelFile = Dts.Variables("sFilePath").Value.ToString
    connstr = GetExcelConnString()

    excelConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connstr)
    excelConnection.Open()

    tablesInFile = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables")
    tableCount = tablesInFile.Rows.Count

    For Each tablenameInFile In tablesInFile.Rows
        curTable = tablenameInFile.Item("TABLE_NAME").ToString.Trim.ToLower

        If curTable.IndexOf("sheet1$") >= 0 Then   'change this to be part of the sheet name that you are looking for.  It should be unique to the specific sheet
            blnFound = True
            ReDim excelTables(tableIndex)
            excelTables(tableIndex) = "[" + curTable + "]"
            tableIndex += 1
        End If
    Next

    excelConnection.Close()

    Dts.Variables("objExcelSheet").Value = excelTables
End Sub

Private Function GetExcelConnString() As String
    Dim sExtendedProperties, sExtension, sFilePath, sExcelConn As String

    sFilePath = Dts.Variables("sFilePath").Value.ToString
    sExtension = sFilePath.Substring(sFilePath.LastIndexOf("."))
    If sExtension.ToLower = ".xlsx" Then
        sExtendedProperties = ";Extended Properties=""EXCEL 12.0;HDR=NO"";"
    ElseIf sExtension.ToLower = ".xls" Then
        sExtendedProperties = ";Extended Properties=""EXCEL 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
    Else
        sExtendedProperties = String.Empty
    End If

    sExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sFilePath & sExtendedProperties

    Return sExcelConn
End Function


Private Sub SetExcelConnString(ByVal sExcelConn As String)
    Dts.Connections("Excel").ConnectionString = sExcelConn
End Sub
```

You can then use a For Each Loop with that object to get each sheetname and process what you need to do when the specified sheet is found.

Answer (score 0):

Your only hope is to use external code assembly (Script Component/ Script Task) to deal with such a situation. SSIS complains about the changed metadata, because it cannot find the old excel file in the excel connection manager. Have you tried using the SSIS Package configuration to change the file name at run time?

This should be able to help you with the part where the work book names are different all the time. But then, you are stuck with the problem of changing sheet names. That is something you need to figure out through a script component I guess.

Comment: First of all I can't change file name every time using package configuration.The whole process should be automated without any human intervention.I got a vb.net script from Naomi .I think the script may help me but still have some limitation too.